# Why would a Python variable be assigned to the wrong value?

Tags: python, debugging

**Reason for asking question/problem I am facing:** my variable 'phonetic' does not update sometimes. I will provide the code, then give an example of the bug:

**purpose of code: output letters of the ukrainian alphabet, and the user has to input a given letters phonetic pronounciation.**

**example of bug: the phonetic variable sometimes has the wrong value (pronunciation) assigned to it.**

```
   import random
   import sys

   print('Welcome to the program. You will be provided with random Ukrainian letters, and it is your job to input the correct phonetic pronounciation of the given letter. Would you like to continue?')

   while True:
       begin = input('type yes or no: ')
       if begin == 'yes':
           break
       if begin == 'no':
           sys.exit()

   alphabet = ["А", "Б", "В", "Г", "Ґ", "Д", "Е", "Є", "Ж", "З", "И", "І", "Ї",
        "Й", "К", "Л", "М", "Н", "О", "П", "Р", "С", "Т", "У", "Ф", "Х", "Ц", "Ч", "Ш", "Щ", "ь", "Ю", "Я"] 

   phonetic = 0


#randomly grab from a list (possibly using choice()) and ask user for input
print("type 'end' to end the program")
while True:
    currentLetter = random.choice(alphabet)
    if currentLetter == alphabet[0]:
        phonetic == 'ah'
    elif currentLetter == alphabet[1]:
        phonetic == 'beh'
    elif currentLetter == alphabet[2]:
        phonetic == 'veh'
    elif currentLetter == alphabet[3]:
        phonetic == 'heh'
    elif currentLetter == alphabet[4]:
        phonetic == 'geh'
    elif currentLetter == alphabet[5]:
        phonetic == 'deh'
    elif currentLetter == alphabet[6]:
        phonetic == 'eh'
    elif currentLetter == alphabet[7]:
        phonetic == 'yeh'
    elif currentLetter == alphabet[8]:
        phonetic == 'zheh'
    elif currentLetter == alphabet[9]:
        phonetic == 'zeh'
    elif currentLetter == alphabet[10]:
        phonetic == 'ih'
    elif currentLetter == alphabet[11]:
        phonetic == 'ee'
    elif currentLetter == alphabet[12]:
        phonetic == 'yih'
    elif currentLetter == alphabet[13]:
        phonetic == 'yot'
    elif currentLetter == alphabet[14]:
        phonetic == 'kah'
    elif currentLetter == alphabet[15]:
        phonetic == 'le'
    elif currentLetter == alphabet[16]:
        phonetic = 'muh'
    elif currentLetter == alphabet[17]:
        phonetic = 'nuh'
    elif currentLetter == alphabet[18]:
        phonetic = 'oh'
    elif currentLetter == alphabet[19]:
        phonetic = 'peh'
    elif currentLetter == alphabet[20]:
        phonetic = 'ruh'
    elif currentLetter == alphabet[21]:
        phonetic = 'suh'
    elif currentLetter == alphabet[22]:
        phonetic = 'te'
    elif currentLetter == alphabet[23]:
        phonetic = 'ooh'
    elif currentLetter == alphabet[24]:
        phonetic = 'fuh'
    elif currentLetter == alphabet[25]:
        phonetic = 'kha'
    elif currentLetter == alphabet[26]:
        phonetic = 'tse'
    elif currentLetter == alphabet[27]:
        phonetic = 'cheh'
    elif currentLetter == alphabet[28]:
        phonetic = 'shah'
    elif currentLetter == alphabet[29]:
        phonetic = 'shcha'
    elif currentLetter == alphabet[30]:
        phonetic = 'myakih znak'
    elif currentLetter == alphabet[31]:
        phonetic = 'yooh'
    elif currentLetter == alphabet[32]:
        phonetic = 'yah'
        
    print('Type in the phonetic spelling of ' + currentLetter + ':')
    userInput = input()
    if userInput == phonetic:
        print('nice work!')
    elif userInput == 'end':
        print('Thanks for playing!')
        break
    else :
        print('Your input was incorrect. The correct phonetic spelling is ' + phonetic + '.')
```

Thank you for reading and considering my question.!

Comment: The code becomes much simpler if you use a dictionary where each letter has its pronunciation assigned directly.

Comment: `phonetic == 'zeh'` is not how you do assignment

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with your code snippet above

```
#randomly grab from a list (possibly using choice()) and ask user for input
print("type 'end' to end the program")
while True:
    currentLetter = random.choice(alphabet)
    if currentLetter == alphabet[0]:
        phonetic == 'ah'

    ...

    elif currentLetter == alphabet[15]:
        phonetic == 'le'
```

`=` is used for assignment, `==` is used to compare values for equality.

You need `=` instead of `==`

Comment: For OPs benefit, maybe you can include how = and == differ.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just Try this code , I have made small changes in it. You were mistaking while storing the item in phonetic variable. If we want to store anything in a variable then use assignment operator.

```
ie. phonetic='ssh'
```

by mistake you have used comparison operator('==') instead of assignment operator here.

```
import random
import sys

print('Welcome to the program. You will be provided with random Ukrainian letters, and it is your job to input the correct phonetic pronounciation of the given letter. Would you like to continue?')

while True:
       begin = input('type yes or no: ')
       if begin == 'yes':
           break
       if begin == 'no':
           sys.exit()

alphabet = ["А", "Б", "В", "Г", "Ґ", "Д", "Е", "Є", "Ж", "З", "И", "І", "Ї",
        "Й", "К", "Л", "М", "Н", "О", "П", "Р", "С", "Т", "У", "Ф", "Х", "Ц", "Ч", "Ш", "Щ", "ь", "Ю", "Я"] 

phonetic =''

#randomly grab from a list (possibly using choice()) and ask user for input
print("type 'end' to end the program")
while True:
    currentLetter = random.choice(alphabet)
    if currentLetter == alphabet[0]:
        phonetic = 'ah'
    elif currentLetter == alphabet[1]:
        phonetic = 'beh'
    elif currentLetter == alphabet[2]:
        phonetic = 'veh'
    elif currentLetter == alphabet[3]:
        phonetic = 'heh'
    elif currentLetter == alphabet[4]:
        phonetic = 'geh'
    elif currentLetter == alphabet[5]:
        phonetic = 'deh'
    elif currentLetter == alphabet[6]:
        phonetic = 'eh'
    elif currentLetter == alphabet[7]:
        phonetic = 'yeh'
    elif currentLetter == alphabet[8]:
        phonetic = 'zheh'
    elif currentLetter == alphabet[9]:
        phonetic = 'zeh'
    elif currentLetter == alphabet[10]:
        phonetic ='ih'
    elif currentLetter == alphabet[11]:
        phonetic = 'ee'
    elif currentLetter == alphabet[12]:
        phonetic = 'yih'
    elif currentLetter == alphabet[13]:
        phonetic = 'yot'
    elif currentLetter == alphabet[14]:
        phonetic = 'kah'
    elif currentLetter == alphabet[15]:
        phonetic = 'le'
    elif currentLetter == alphabet[16]:
        phonetic = 'muh'
    elif currentLetter == alphabet[17]:
        phonetic = 'nuh'
    elif currentLetter == alphabet[18]:
        phonetic = 'oh'
    elif currentLetter == alphabet[19]:
        phonetic = 'peh'
    elif currentLetter == alphabet[20]:
        phonetic = 'ruh'
    elif currentLetter == alphabet[21]:
        phonetic = 'suh'
    elif currentLetter == alphabet[22]:
        phonetic = 'te'
    elif currentLetter == alphabet[23]:
        phonetic = 'ooh'
    elif currentLetter == alphabet[24]:
        phonetic = 'fuh'
    elif currentLetter == alphabet[25]:
        phonetic = 'kha'
    elif currentLetter == alphabet[26]:
        phonetic = 'tse'
    elif currentLetter == alphabet[27]:
        phonetic = 'cheh'
    elif currentLetter == alphabet[28]:
        phonetic = 'shah'
    elif currentLetter == alphabet[29]:
        phonetic = 'shcha'
    elif currentLetter == alphabet[30]:
        phonetic = 'myakih znak'
    elif currentLetter == alphabet[31]:
        phonetic = 'yooh'
    elif currentLetter == alphabet[32]:
        phonetic = 'yah'
        
    print('Type in the phonetic spelling of ' + currentLetter + ':')
    userInput = input()
    if userInput == phonetic:
        print('nice work!')
    elif userInput == 'end':
        print('Thanks for playing!')
        break
    else :
        print('Your input was incorrect. The correct phonetic spelling is ' + phonetic + '.')
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply! much appreciated.